# What partition table does Ubuntu create by default?

Tags: partitioning, system-installation

In the "Something else" partitioning menu what partition table (MBR/GPT) does "New Partition Table..." use?

Comment: IF you  boot in UEFI mode it will be gpt, If you boot in BIOS mode it will be MBR unless drive is  blank and somewhere over 1.5GB even though gpt only required if over 2TiB. Otherwise if you want gpt with BIOS boot you need to partition in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no default partition format for Linux. It can handle many partition formats.

For a Linux-only system, either use MBR or GPT will work fine. MBR is more common, but GPT has some advantages, including support for larger disks. The main issue with GPT is compatibility; not all OSes support it, and some can't boot from GPT on BIOS-based computers.
For just a Linux system, I'd choose GPT. If you need to dual-boot with Windows, go with MBR.

That said, if you have a newer system, a very large hard drive, and you use UEFI I`d go with GPT.

The installer will use GPT automatically for disks over 2 TiB, if you choose the automatic option.  It will create either the bios_grub or efi system partition depending on whether the machine supports UEFI or not.

So to answer your question, it depends on your system, hard drive size, and whether you have UEFI or not.

Master Boot Record (MBR) - Most IBM-based PC storage units use this partition table format. MBR is often referred to as the msdos partition table. The MBR can only support storage devices up to two terabytes. MBR supports the concept of logical and primary partitions. A storage unit with the MBR table can only have up to four primary partitions. Many users wanting to make a multiboot system with more than four Linux distros often have the problem of not being able to support more partitions. Remember, logical partitions cannot be made bootable. Multiboot systems must use a different partition table discussed later.<sup>[Linux.org](http://www.linux.org/threads/partition-tables.4895/)</sup>

GUID Partition Table (GPT) - Some IBM-based PC storage units have GPT, although it is usually because the user reformatted from MBR to GPT. However, most Intel-based Mac systems use GPT by default. The GPT partition table offers many improvements over MBR. GPT can support storage units up to over nine zettabytes. GPT is also the most highly recommended partition table for computers needing more than four operating systems on one hard-drive. For example, if a computer with a ten terabyte hard-disk is meant to be a multiboot system for seven different Linux distros, then GPT should be used. Most Unix and Unix-like operating systems can fully support GPT. However, most Windows systems cannot run on a GPT partition table. As for Mac systems, only the Intel-based ones can boot from GPT.[<sup>Linux.org</sup>](http://www.linux.org/threads/partition-tables.4895/)

Comment: I think you missed the point of the question entirely. I'm pretty sure OP is asking the default partition table picked by the Ubiquity installer, *not* recommendations on picking one. I'm pretty sure Ubiquity has a default, since I don't think I have ever seen it giving a choice.

Comment: @muru The OP wants to know What partition table does Ubuntu create by default.  That's the point, there is none.  that's why I started by "There is no default partition format". :)

Comment: so if I install Ubuntu now on a fresh disk it will create partitions on thin air instead of on a partition table? O.o Of course it has a default.

Comment: @muru No need for sarcasm. No it won't create partitions on thin air.  If you have an older system, it will create an MSDOS partition, and newer system that supports UEFI, it will create a GPT partition table.  If you have any different info, by all means go ahead and edit, or answer.  Thanks :)

Comment: yes! That's the answer, not the long post written above. Might make a great answer with some sources.

Comment: @muru no sources, I just tried this on an older machine, and since my other machine is new, it created a GPT partition table.

Comment: I'd been looking through Ubiquity sources, but reached a dead-end [here](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/vivid/ubiquity/vivid/view/head:/ubiquity/plugins/ubi-partman.py#L2877). AFAICT `debian-installer`'s `partman` default is MBR, GPT has to be set.